# Как одной гиперссылкой открыть любую страницу сайта в виде кода?

Tags: python, веб-программирование, парсер

Просматриваю сейчас код одного разработчика, вроде всё понятно, но одно не могу понять. Он использует ссылку, для того, чтобы открыть информацию о любой странице сайта в json формате (вроде), подставив лишь номер страницы в эту ссылку. Вопрос, как получить такую ссылку для любой страницы? [https://market.dota2.net/ajax/i_popularity///all/{0}/56/0;100000/all/all](https://market.dota2.net/ajax/i_popularity///all/%7B0%7D/56/0;100000/all/all) вот ссылка, она отсылает на любую страницу с предметами сайта только в виде кода, достаточно лишь вместо {0} поставить любое целочисленное значение. Откуда можно достать эту ссылку?

Comment: Ну например, если сайт написан на каком-нибудь js-фреймворке, то бэкенд и фронтенд общаются как раз через такие jsonы. Нужно открыть в браузере инструменты разработчика, открыть вкладку network и посмотреть какие запросы делает браузер к серверу и какие ответы получает.

Comment: Так вот я просмотрел все ссылаемые объекты во вкладке network, нигде не было чего-то похожего на это. Возможно нужен какой-то плагин, либо я слепой.